# Replacing multiple non-slice specific values of a list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

Suppose I have two variables a and b:

`a=[0,1,-1,3,4,-1,6,7,-1,9]`

`b=[0,3,6,9,1,4,7,2,5,8]`

I need to specifically move the 2, 5, and 8 from b and replace the -1's with the 2,5, and 8 in their respective places. I also need to do so as condensed as possible to make my program run faster.

The desired result being that

`a==[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

The best solution that I could come up with that works is:

`a[2]=b[7]`

`a[5]=b[8]`

`a[8]=b[9]`

I then thought of using the following to do so:

`a[2,5,8]=b[7,8,9]`

or

`a[2,5,8]=b[7:9]`

However, I get an error message for both

`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`

Is there any way I can condense this down to a single line, or at least a simpler form than the 3 lines I already have?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The problem is not well specified. What exactly is the **rule that tells you** which values to replace? For example, will it always be the ones in specific positions? Do you need to check each time, to see which of the existing `a` values are equal to `-1`? Something else? **Why** do we need to solve this problem? For example, why can I not answer the question by saying "use the code: `a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`"? Depending on the actual requirement, this is most likely a duplicate of an existing question, but it's not possible to know **which** yet.

Comment: `a[2::3] = b[-3:]` happens to work for this example, but depending on *why* you need it, it might be too specific.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and see if that helps you:

**Note** - you don't have to hard-code the position, it gives you more flexibility.

```py
it = iter([2, 5, 8])        #  the numbers to change in

A = [0,1,-1,3,4,-1,6,7,-1,9]

A = [x if x != -1 else next(it)  for x in A]  # check condition & act accordingly 

print(A)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a[2], a[5], a[8] = b[7], b[8], b[9]
```

or

```
a[2], a[5], a[8] = b[7:10]
```

Comment: remember that if you use slices, the last part is not included, that's why it's 10 instead of 9.